# how to prevent search engine to index only one part of my page

Tags: html, indexing, search-engine

what is the best way to do it ?

put it in  iframe  .

set this section after load with javascript ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relevant to Yahoo:

http://searchengineland.com/yahoo-supports-new-robots-nocontent-tag-to-block-indexing-within-a-page-11120

Loading content by Javascript would also prevent it.

An iframe i don't think would, as it can see the source and can eventually crawl it (unless the robot file specifies that file as uncrawelable or the meta tag (and only for spiders that conform to robots.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Would this help? [Robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt)

Comment: Robots.txt is only relevant for a while link rather than individual content within a page.